# Como extrair dados separados de uma string fora de formato

Tags: r, string

Ao extrair dados de um pdf no R, extraindo textos linha a linha, tenho a seguinte situação. Uma string de interesse que vem com três informações separadas por espaços longos, como exemplificado a seguir

```
a <- "WDFG V/AA 8952                              123546514            sdfasfasfa"
```

preciso extrair apenas "WDFG V/AA 8952"

Como são muitos pdfs, precisaria de um método para inserir em um looping e dar escala ao processo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que esta expressão regular resolve o problema.

Os dados são estes:

```
a <- c("João Fernando Freitas                             123546514            sdfasfasfa",
       "WDFG V/AA 8952                              123546514            sdfasfasfa")
```

E a expressão regular.

```
b <- sub("(^[[:alnum:]]*| ) {2,}([[:alnum:]]| )*$", "\\1", a)
b <- trimws(b)
b
#[1] "João Fernando Freitas" "WDFG V/AA 8952"
```

Se pretende inserir num loop, talvez seja melhor por o código acima numa função.

```
extraiNome <- function(x){
  b <- sub("(^[[:alnum:]]*| ) {2,}([[:alnum:]]| )*$", "\\1", x)
  trimws(b)
}

extraiNome(a)
#[1] "João Fernando Freitas" "WDFG V/AA 8952"
```

Comment: obrigado, resolveu o problema

Comment: Rui, por favor, poderia me ajudar com uma adaptação do código para extrair o primeiro termo da string da pergunta como eu editei agora , grato

preciso extrair apenas "WDFG V/AA 8952"

Comment: @HenriqueFariadeOliveira Acabei de testar e a função na resposta faz isso, também com a nova string.